# Google Spreadsheets: referencing automatically cell data from a dynamic list of files

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a a list of invoices created with Google Spreadsheet. Now I would like to retrieve the data inside of those invoices to create another spreadsheet called "All" that contains a row for each invoice.

```
Name Phone Street

John  677  Main
Mary  897  Niceday
```

Is there any way to do that automatically instead of referencing cells one by one?

One more: imagine, I add a new invoice file, I would like that after addding it, the Name, Phone and Street inside it, **were added automatically to the "All" file**. Is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the files are located inside a single drive folder, then you can retrieve all of the data from each spreadsheet file and add it to your main spreadsheet file using an onOpen function.

```
function onOpen(){
   // This active sheet.
   var mainSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   // To store all of the invoice data
   var invoiceData = [];
   // Get all files inside a drive folder
   var files = DocsList.getFolderById("DRIVE FOLDER ID").getFiles();
   // For each file in the folder
   for (var i in files) {
      // Open the current spreadsheet in the interation
      var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(files[i].getId());
      // Get the contents as an array and add it to invoiceData
      invoiceData.push(thisSpreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues());
   }
   // Clear all content in active sheet
   mainSpreadsheet.getDataRange.clearContent();
   // Get the write range from the number of values inside invoiceData
   var writeRange = mainSpreadsheet.getRange(1,1,invoiceData.length, invoiceData[0].length)
   // Add the data to the spreadsheet. 
   writeRange.setValues(invoiceData);
}
```

This is an example and untested. It will vary depending on headings in your file but it should dget you started.